# AddImageFilter error in SimpleITK

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, addition, itk

In a C# project, I ve got error using the `AddImageFilter` which is provided in the SimpleITK. Is there a common mistake that happens when trying to add two images with this filter? For example, maybe there is a rule `the images should be both double or int`.

The error I get is:

> Image2 for AddImageFilter doesnt match type or dimension!

Answer (score 0):

In a certain sense, your supposition is right. I couldn't been able to find the exact error you've got, but I found this [sitkAddImageFilter implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK/pull/1/files). If you look at the `AddImageFilter::Execute()` function, at line 33, you'll find this exception been throwed:

```
std::cerr << "Both image for add filter don't match type or dimension!" << std::endl;
```

that seems related to yours (maybe the slight difference is just related to a different version of ITK). And that exception is throwed whenever this is verified:

```
if ( type != image2->GetDataType() || dimension != image2->GetDimension() )
```

So, a condition for the AddImageFilter is that **both dimensions must be the same, and the metadata associated with the images must agree**. This makes sense, because matrices addition is doable only when their dimensions match (and, of course, when they contain the same kind of informations).

If you are trying to add two different kinds of images (as an example: a DICOM with a TIFF), I suggest to convert at least one of them, in a way to have both of them in the same "metadata space".

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a little vague and should be improved.

Many filters which take more than one image as input expect the following that pixel type, dimension, size, spacing and orientation to be same. The error message you got indicates that the pixel type or the size do not match. Likely emanating from the code generated from is line:

https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK/blob/master/TemplateComponents/ExecuteNoParameters.cxx.in#L8

I'd recommend printing your two images as strings to examine the meta-data to determine the difference.